# (Codesandbox, Vue) 'Property or method "children" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, state-management, codesandbox

I am currently building a State Manager, which can be integrated into multiple Frontend Framework, including Vue.
To demonstrate the usage of the State Manger in Vue, I created a simple codesandbox.
Because it is always nice to have a live code example, which can be promoted in the Readme.
But somehow, I am always getting this (see below) error in the codesandbox.

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "children" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

The above error **only** occurs in the codesandbox showing the `editor + preview`.
Locally or in a separate tab (which displays only the `preview`)
it works as expected (without error).

Codesandbox (Error): 
https://codesandbox.io/s/agilets-first-state-i5xxs?file=/src/main.js

Codesandbox Preview on separate tap (no Error): 
https://i5xxs.csb.app/

Local Project (no Error): 
https://github.com/agile-ts/agile/tree/master/examples/vue/develop/my-project

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.
But it has something to do with my State Manager,
since the default [vue codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) works fine.

Comment: I looked at your CodeSandbox.  I did notice that you are importing and calling a function ```generateId()```.  In order for Vue to use it, pretty sure you need to add it to your instance methods: ```methods: { generateId }```.  Then call it with ```this.generateId()```.

Comment: I don't think so.. because why would it work locally then.. but I'll give it a try.. thanks ;D Edit: I removed the function from the example, but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignore that error. This is a [bug in Codesandbox](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/2095#issuecomment-510655208) and not directly caused by your own code. One of their [developers commented on Apr 13](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/2095#issuecomment-818500869) that the issue is low priority, so it likely won't be fixed anytime soon.

Comment: alright thanks for the information.. as it looks like it has something to do with logging the vue instance.. and as soon I had diesabled the logging it works fine.. thanks for the hint ;D

Comment: Ahhh I haven't fix that error yet, it's still happening for me more than a year later. A bot closed the issue before it was fixed. Several people commented that it should be open because they are also having an issue but no one from Codesandbox responds.

Comment: I was getting this same error when I had a method that was performing a `console.log()`. Once I removed the `console.log()`, the error went away.